# Accordion - Collapse View inSide the TouchableOpacity doesn't work

Tags: react-native, reactive-programming, react-native-ios, react-native-listview

In my project I use the accordion for expand and collapse. its working fine. in collapse view I set one TouchableOpacity, but its event doesn't work.

Please See the code ,

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View ,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  Button,
  TouchableHighlight,
  FlatList,
  TouchableNativeFeedback,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';

import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view'
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import Accordion from 'react-native-collapsible/Accordion';
import { List, ListItem ,Avatar} from 'react-native-elements'



  var options = {
    title: 'Select Avatar',
    customButtons: [
      {name: 'fb', title: 'Choose Photo from Facebook'},
    ],
    storageOptions: {
      skipBackup: true,
      path: 'images'
    }
  };

  const SECTIONS = [
     {
       title: 'LUCAS F.',
       content: 'NORTH BONDI',
       jobName : 'CHILD CARE CENTER',
       Address : '32 LEVEY STREET \n GREEN SQUARE',
       job : 'GENERAL LABOURER',
       jobTime : [
         {
           date : '06/03',
           start : '7 am',
           break : '30 min',
           finish : '3:30',
         },
         {
           date : '06/03',
           start : '7 am',
           break : '30 min',
           finish : '3:30',
         },
         {
           date : '06/03',
           start : '7 am',
           break : '30 min',
           finish : '3:30',
         },
         {
           date : '06/03',
           start : '7 am',
           break : '30 min',
           finish : '3:30',
         },{
           date : '06/03',
           start : '7 am',
           break : '30 min',
           finish : '3:30',
         },
         {
           date : '06/03',
           start : '7 am',
           break : '30 min',
           finish : '3:30',
         },
         {
           date : '06/03',
           start : '7 am',
           break : '30 min',
           finish : '3:30',
         },
         {
           date : '06/03',
           start : '7 am',
           break : '30 min',
           finish : '3:30',
         }
       ]
     },
     {
       title: 'MATTHEW N.',
       content: 'NORTH BONDI.',
       jobName : 'CHILD CARE CENTER',
       Address : '32 LEVEY STREET \n GREEN SQUARE',
       job : 'GENERAL LABOURER',
       jobTime : [
         {
           date : '06/03',
           start : '7 am',
           break : '30 min',
           finish : '3:30',
         },
         {
           date : '06/03',
           start : '7 am',
           break : '30 min',
           finish : '3:30',
         }
       ]
     },
     {
        title: 'NEIL E.',
        content: 'GREEN SQUARE',
        jobName : 'CHILD CARE CENTER',
        Address : '32 LEVEY STREET \n GREEN SQUARE',
        job : 'GENERAL LABOURER',
        jobTime : [
          {
            date : '06/03',
            start : '7 am',
            break : '30 min',
            finish : '3:30',
          }
        ]

      }
   ];


export default  class TimeSheet extends Component {

      state = {
        emailID: '',
        password: '',
        confirmPassword : '',
        firstName : '',
        lastName : '',
        role : '',
        phone : '',

     }



     constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {text: ''};
         this.state = {
           titleText: "ADD A",
           bodyText: 'MANAGER',
           heightDynamic : 0,
         };
       }

       spadeOptionPush = () =>{
         Alert.alert('You tapped the button!')
       }



    //  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    //    title: `${navigation.state.params.user}`,
    //  });

    _renderHeader(section) {
        return (
          <View style={styles.header}>
            <View style = {{width : '30%' , height : '100%' , alignItems : 'center' , justifyContent : 'center' , marginLeft : 20}}>
              <Avatar
                rounded
                medium
                source={{uri: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg"}}
                activeOpacity={0.7}/>
            </View>
            <View style = {{width : '70%' , height : '100%' , flexDirection : 'column' , alignItems : 'flex-start' , justifyContent : 'center'}}>
              <Text style={[styles.headerText , {fontSize : 17}]}>{section.title}</Text>
              <Text style={[styles.headerText , {fontSize : 14}]}>{section.content}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        );
      }


    _renderContent(section) {

      heightDynamic = (section.jobTime.length) * 70;
      console.log(heightDynamic);

        return (
          <View style={styles.backExpandView}>

            <View style = {styles.mainExpandView}>

              <Image style={{width: '80%', height: 15,justifyContent: 'center' ,alignItems: 'center' , marginLeft : '10%' , marginTop : 10}}
                       source={require("./Images/jobDetails.png")} />

               <Text style = {styles.jobTitle}>Job Name</Text>
               <Text style = {styles.jobDescription}>{section.jobName}</Text>

               <Text style = {styles.jobTitle}>Address</Text>
               <Text style = {styles.jobDescription}>{section.Address}</Text>

               <Text style = {styles.jobTitle}>Job</Text>
               <Text style = {styles.jobDescription}>{section.job}</Text>
               <Text style = {styles.jobTitle}></Text>

            </View>

            {/*LIST VIEW*/}

            <List style={{borderBottomWidth: 0 , borderTopWidth: 0 , height : heightDynamic}}
                  containerStyle={{marginTop : 10 , backgroundColor : 'transparent'}}>


              <FlatList
                data={section.jobTime}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                  <ListItem containerStyle={{height: 70, backgroundColor : '#070808' , marginLeft : 10 , marginRight : 10, borderBottomColor: 'transparent'}}
                    hideChevron = {true}
                    title={
                      <View style = {{height : '100%' , width : '100%' , flexDirection : 'row' , alignItems : 'flex-start' , justifyContent : 'flex-start'}}>

                        <View style = {{width : '25%' , height : '100%'  , justifyContent : 'center' , alignItems : 'center'}}>
                          <Text style ={{fontFamily: 'Gotham-Black',fontSize : 14 ,color: 'white'}}>{item.date}</Text>
                        </View>

                        <View style = {{width : '25%' , height : '100%' , justifyContent : 'center' , alignItems : 'center' , flexDirection : 'column'}}>
                          <Text style ={{fontFamily: 'Gotham-Black',fontSize : 14 ,color: '#DE6E26'}}>{item.start}</Text>
                          <Text style ={{fontFamily: 'Gotham-Light',fontSize : 14 ,color: 'white'}}>Start</Text>
                        </View>

                        <View style = {{width : '25%' , height : '100%' , justifyContent : 'center' , alignItems : 'center' , flexDirection : 'column'}}>
                          <Text style ={{fontFamily: 'Gotham-Black',fontSize : 14 ,color: '#DE6E26'}}>{item.break}</Text>
                          <Text style ={{fontFamily: 'Gotham-Light',fontSize : 14 ,color: 'white'}}>Break</Text>

                        </View>

                        <View style = {{width : '25%' , height : '100%' , justifyContent : 'center' , alignItems : 'center' , flexDirection : 'column'}}>
                          <Text style ={{fontFamily: 'Gotham-Black',fontSize : 14 ,color: '#DE6E26'}}>{item.finish}</Text>
                          <Text style ={{fontFamily: 'Gotham-Light',fontSize : 14 ,color: 'white'}}>End</Text>
                        </View>
                      </View>
                    }
                  />
                )}
              />
            </List>


            {/*Approved*/}

            {/* <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.changeStyle()}/> */}

            <TouchableNativeFeedback
                    onPress={this.approvalSection}>
                  <View style={{width: 150, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
                    <Text style={{margin: 30}}>Button</Text>
                  </View>
            </TouchableNativeFeedback>

            <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                    onPress={this.approvalSection}>
                  <View style={{width: 150, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
                    <Text style={{margin: 30}}>Button</Text>
                  </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

            <Button
              onPress={() => {Alert.alert('You tapped the button!')}}
              title="Learn More"
              color="#841584"
              accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
            />

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.spadeOptionPush}}>

            {/* <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.approvalSection}> */}
              <View style ={[styles.thirdV ,{backgroundColor : '#7DA137',height : 90}]}>
                <View style = {{height : '100%' , width : '30%' , alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                  <Image style={{width: 20, height: 34,justifyContent: 'center' ,alignItems: 'center'}}
                         source={require("./Images/iconTimeStemp.png")} />
                </View>
                <View style = {{height : '100%' , width : '40%' , justifyContent: 'center' ,alignItems: 'flex-start', flexDirection : 'column'}}>
                  <Text style = {{fontFamily: 'Gotham-Black',fontSize : 16 ,color: 'white'}}>
                    APPROVED
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <View style = {{height : '100%' , width : '30%' , alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                    <Image style={{width: 27, height: 22,justifyContent: 'center' ,alignItems: 'center'}}
                           source={require("./Images/arrow.png")} />
                </View>
              </View>
           </TouchableOpacity>

         {/*Delete Job*/}

         <TouchableOpacity>
           <View style ={[styles.thirdV ,{height : 90 ,  backgroundColor : '#161617' , marginBottom : 20}]}>
             <View style = {{height : '100%' , width : '30%' , alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
               <Image style={{width: 25, height: 25,justifyContent: 'center' ,alignItems: 'center'}}
                      source={require("./Images/addWorkers.png")} />
             </View>
             <View style = {{height : '100%' , width : '40%' , justifyContent: 'center' ,alignItems: 'flex-start', flexDirection : 'column'}}>
               <Text style = {{fontFamily: 'Gotham-Black',fontSize : 14 ,color: '#DE6E26'}}>
                 REPORT
               </Text>
               <Text style = {{fontFamily: 'Gotham-Black',fontSize : 14 ,color: 'white'}}>
                 A PROBLEM
               </Text>
             </View>
             <View style = {{height : '100%' , width : '30%' , alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
               <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => navigate('AddManager' , {user : 'Add Manager'})}>
                 <Image style={{width: 27, height: 22,justifyContent: 'center' ,alignItems: 'center'}}
                        source={require("./Images/arrow.png")} />
               </TouchableHighlight>
             </View>

           </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        );
      }


     render(){

       const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

        return (

          <ScrollView style = {styles.scrollSty}>
             <View style = {styles.container}>
                <Image style = {styles.imageSty}
                  source={require('./Images/topImage.png')}
                />

               {/* Add View with Row element. */}

                 <View style ={styles.hireView}>
                   <View style = {{height : '100%' , width : '30%' , alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                     <Image style={{width: 30, height: 30,justifyContent: 'center' ,alignItems: 'center'}}
                            source={require("./Images/hireJob.png")} />
                   </View>
                   <View style = {{height : '100%' , width : '60%' , justifyContent: 'center' ,alignItems: 'flex-start', flexDirection : 'column'}}>
                     <Text style = {{fontFamily: 'Gotham-Black',fontSize : 17 ,color: '#DE8C22'}}>
                       TIMESHEET
                     </Text>
                     <Text style = {{fontFamily: 'Gotham-Black',fontSize : 17 ,color: 'white'}}>
                       PENDING{"\n"}
                       APPROVALS
                     </Text>

                   </View>
                 </View>


                 <View style = {{marginTop : 20 , marginBottom : 10 ,width : '100%' , height : 20 , alignItems : 'center' , justifyContent : 'center'}}>
                   <Image style = {{height : 15}}
                     source={require('./Images/activeJob.png')}
                   />
                 </View>

                 <Accordion
                    sections={SECTIONS}
                    renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
                    renderContent={this._renderContent}
                  />

             </View>
         </ScrollView>
        );
     }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({

      imageProfile :{
        height : 35,
        width : 35,
      },
      imageSty : {
        marginLeft  : 10,
        marginRight :10,
      },
      addManagerTxtStyle :{
        fontFamily: 'Gotham-Bold',
        fontSize : 18,
        textAlign : 'left',
      },
      textSty : {
        fontFamily: 'Gotham-Bold',
        fontSize : 15,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        marginLeft : 35,
        marginTop : 20,
        color : '#C46427',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'flex-start',

      },
      scrollSty :{
        flex : 1,
        backgroundColor: '#141415',
      },
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop : 30,
      },
      titleImageStyle :{
         margin : 25,
         justifyContent: 'center',
         alignItems: 'center',
      },
      emailIdSt : {
        marginBottom : 5,
        fontSize : 17,
        marginTop : 10,
        marginLeft : 15,
        marginRight : 15,
      },
      input: {
        fontFamily: 'Gotham-Thin',
        marginLeft: 35,
        marginRight: 35,
         height: 40,
         backgroundColor : '#B1B1B1',
         paddingLeft : 10,

    },
    submitButton: {
       backgroundColor: '#DE8C22',
       padding: 10,
       margin: 15,
       height: 100,
       width : '90%',
    },

    submitButtonText:{
        justifyContent: 'center',
        fontFamily: 'Gotham-Bold',
        fontSize : 20,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: 'white',
    },
    viewStyleRow :{
      flexDirection: 'row',
      height : 120,
      width : '100%',
      justifyContent: 'flex-start',
      alignItems: 'center',
      backgroundColor : 'white',
    },
    viewAddManagerText:{
      height : 60,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'flex-start',

    },
    headerTitleStyle :{
      marginLeft : 25,
      marginRight : 25,
      marginTop : 15,
      fontFamily: 'Gotham-Thin',
      fontSize : 18,
      color: '#DE8C22',
    },
    thirdV :{
       flexDirection : 'row',
       marginLeft : 10,
       marginRight : 10,
     },
     hireView :{
       marginTop : 30,
       height : 90,
       backgroundColor : 'transparent',
       flexDirection : 'row',
     },
    header :{
      backgroundColor : '#7DA137',
      height : 80,
      width : '100%',
      flexDirection : 'row',
      justifyContent : 'center',
      alignItems : 'center',
    },
    headerText :{
      fontFamily: 'Gotham-Black',
      color: 'white',
    },
    backExpandView :{
      backgroundColor : '#7DA137',
      margin : 0,
      height : '100%',
    },
    mainExpandView : {
      marginLeft : 10,
      marginRight : 10,
      marginBottom : 0,
      backgroundColor : '#161617',
      flexDirection : 'column',
      alignItems : 'flex-start',
    },
    jobTitle :{
      marginTop : 10,
      paddingLeft : 10,
      fontFamily: 'Gotham-Light',
      fontSize : 16,
      color: '#DE8C22',
    },
    jobDescription :{
      marginTop : 5,
      paddingLeft : 10,
      fontFamily: 'Gotham-Black',
      fontSize : 14,
      color: 'white',
    }
  });
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

IT'S WORKING FOR ME :

```
<Button onPress={() => {Alert.alert('You tapped the button!')}}
              title="Learn More"
              color="#841584"
              accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
            />
```

IT'S NOT WORKING FOR ME :

```
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.spadeOptionPush}}/>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Is that expo link correct? There's no touchableopacity in there.

Comment: @digit, I will update expo linkd

Comment: @digit now update code.and issue also.

Answer (score 0):

this won't work because it's not valid jsx syntax.

you have to do either

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.spadeOptionPush()}}/>
```

or

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.spadeOptionPush}}/>
```

read jsx [Functions as Children](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#functions-as-children) for detail.